# AngularJS $http custom header for all requests

Tags: angularjs, http

I was wondering if there is any way to configure all $http requests header with adding custom info. Something like config :

```
 var config = {headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    };
```

But for all $http calls I will make in different services. I'm sure there is a solution :D.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interceptor for all http requests in angularJS 1.0.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062493/interceptor-for-all-http-requests-in-angularjs-1-0-x)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can create a `$http` interceptor to extend your header:

```js
myapp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {

      config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==';
      config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';

      return config;
    }
  };
});

myapp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: May be a silly question to ask, but why the authorization token has prefix "Basic " ?

Comment: it's just an example :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The `Authorization` header has a few default options such as `Basic base64encodedStringSeperatedWithA:` or `Bearer tokenString` in the form of `Authorization: <type> <credentials>` which is standard throughout the internet.

Comment: @DeanMeehan Thanks. You're not to late to reply, it's just one year anyway.

Comment: Stackoverflow will last forever, I just thought I'd leave some information for others searching the same question! :)

Answer (score 23):

A simpler solution could be to use Angular's `run` block:

```
app.run(['$http', function ($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==';
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
}]);
```

Note: This solution allows you to pass the static value only one time since the `run` block executes only once.

Comment: Problem with this if user logs in after run time he doesn't ave authorization token yet, that's why better use interceptor

Comment: Yup, I know that but I answered according to the question as the author wanted to add header in **all** request:-)

Comment: I'm trying this in angular v1.0.6 but the property 'common' does not exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
  use the folllowing code and  you can also control  $http timeout from 
 config setting.    
 'use strict';
   var app = angular.module('b2capp', []);
   var apiRequestCount = 0;      
   app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($rootScope, $q) {
       return {
           request: function (config) {
               apiRequestCount++;
                //   config.timeout =300000;
              return config;
          },
          response: function (response) {
               return response;
          },
           responseError: function (rejection) {
             switch (rejection.status) {
                   case 408:
                        console.log('connection timed out');
                        break;
              }
               // return $q.reject(rejection);
               return rejection;
            }
          }
       })
    });
 }]);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var headers = {
            //'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password),
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                 }
    $http.post(url + 'Search_6e', reqCookie, {
                   headers
            })
            .then(function Success(response) {               
                 $scope.myData = resultData;
                 console.log($scope.myData);
           }, function myError(response) {
              //error code
    });
```