# Web API return html instead of JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Have made an angular js solution with the controllers designed as WepAPIs. When I test in my local the solution runs fine . But when i deploy to a server the WebAPI does not seem to give a correct response .

The request body and the api path is correct . Although i get a response code of 200 in the response of calling the API , the content type in the response is text/html; charset=utf-8 rather than JSON and my index page is being returned in the response as html.

Am I missing any server configuration ? Some server configuration has to be done for an WebAPI project ?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting an error page in response.  Have you read it?

Comment: Also sounds like you might have your project/server configured to always return index.html, which in general is what you want except for where you make API calls and calls to retrieve other files.

Comment: Accept headers set right? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29944997/angularjs-http-custom-header-for-all-requests

Comment: Not sure if it helps someone else - I had this problem when I was concurrently running two versions of the same app in development env.